# RoR Rnder a partial cant find method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a classes User and Company, I want to re-use the users partial as the to render company staff.

In my `CompaniesController` I have:

```
def staff
  @company=Company.find(params[:id])
  @users=@company.works_fors.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  @title=@company.name+" staff."
end
```

And in my `staff.html.erb` template I have:

```
<% if @users.any? %>
  <ul class="users follow">
    <%= render @users %> 
  </ul>
  <%= will_paginate %>
<% end %>
```

This is the `works_fors/_works_for` partial:

```
<%= render :partial => 'user' %>
```

Which Renders

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.developer? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

However this throws an error on the user object as it cant find the method

**undefined local variable or method `user' for~~**

I think this is because Im calling the user object from within companies but there is a defined relationship, or do I need to redefine in companies ?

Comment: Is `WorksFor` a model? Or is it just a scope? Is it backed by a database table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell, but it appears that what you call `@users` in your controller is in fact not a `User` collection, but a `WorkFor` collection.

```
@users = @company.works_fors...
```

What you mean is:

```
@works_fors = @company.works_fors...
```

This means that `staff.html.erb` is working with a `works_for` collection. So you should rename the variable in your template to avoid confusion.

```
# staff.html.erb
<% if @works_fors.any? %>
  <ul class="users follow">
    <%= render @works_fors %> 
  </ul>
  <%= will_paginate @works_fors %>
<% end %>
```

Now we know we are rendering a `works_for` partial. So an instance of `works_for` is be available inside the partial. We need to ask it for its associated user instance, and pass it to the render method.

```
 # works_fors/_works_for.html.erb
 <%= render works_for.user %>
```

As a bonus, you can save yourself some queries by preloading the users.

```
@works_fors = @company.works_fors.includes(:user)...
```

Comment: "you should rename the variable in your template to avoid confusion.
"

The Rails naming conventions and scope are causing me such a nightmare - i think I get it then its gone, theres too many factors hurting my head.

Comment: @StevenMoffat it's very simple if you follow the conventions. When you do `render @users`, Rails will derive the name of the partial form the class of each element of the collection. Implicitly, it calls [`to_partial_path`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Conversion/to_partial_path) on each user, which returns `_user` (derived from the class name). In this case you were loading a `works_fors` collection. So the behaviour is as expected. I do understand that it can be confusing in the beginning through. But keep at it. It becomes second nature soon enough.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed - Ive worked through this and now renders a page if theres no works_fors , however if there is staff brings this argument

The @companies variable appears to be empty. Did you forget to pass the collection object for will_paginate?

If I remove the paginate in the controller and the view then it renders the page with my staff !!! go figure :/

Comment: @StevenMoffat I suspect you will want to do this: `<%= will_paginate @works_fors %>` Pagination should be on the `@works_fors` variable.

Comment: it was

<%= will_paginate @works_for %>

:) thanks so much for your time and patience - i'll stick with it

Comment: @StevenMoffat my pleasure. Good luck with this stuff!